# Package Relative Paths in R

Tags: r, r-package

I've written a few functions for a package that use relative paths like:

```
"./data/foobar.rds"
```

Here's an example function:

```
foo <- function(x) { 
x <- readRDS("./data/bar.rds")
return(x)
}
```

Now, if I were to be working in the development path of the package, this works as I expect. But when I load the package, this path uses the current working directory rather than the relative path of the package.

How does one set it up such that the path for functions within a package maintain their within the package relative paths?

Comment: See `?system.file` and `?.path.package`

Comment: So, something like `x <- readRDS(paste(system.file(package="pkgName"),"/data/bar.rds",sep=""))`?

Comment: If you want something OS independant try x <- `readRDS(file.path(system.file(package = "pkgName"), "data", "bar.rds"))`

Comment: If you’re using ‘box’, you can use `box::file()`. If you’re not using ‘box’, and you’re not using packages, there’s no clean solution that always works. The ‘here’ package works in *some* circumstances but not always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Andrie notes, you can use [`system.file`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system.file.html), which "finds the full file names of files in packages etc."

```
x <- readRDS(system.file("help", "aliases.rds", package="MASS"))
```

Comment: `dir(system.file("help", package = "MASS"))`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen -- The call to `system.file()` resolves to `<your-R-library-location>/MASS/help/aliases.rds`, which is where the file to be read resides. (All initial unnamed arguments get soaked up by `...`, which `system.file()` treats as a set of subdirectories and files, from which it constructs paths within the given package.)